# OrientDB Object Database and JPA reliability

Tags: orientdb

Question: how reliable is the object DB and JPA layer on top of OrientDB nowadays?

I remember from the 2.0.x times that there were quite a few issues with it...

Answer (score 0):

now many bugs are fixed, if you want you can try the new version 3.0

[Here](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/release/3.0/What-is-new-in-OrientDB-3.0.html) the link of all the new features